# How can you stop a Zepto animation?

Tags: animation, cordova, zepto

I am working with Zepto and Phonegap to create a target that moves over the page. When it's touched, I want the animation to end. I can't find any command that stops the animation. Changing opacity to 0 and starting a new animation don't work either. I can trigger it when it's touched, I'm just having trouble figuring out what the command is to stop the animation, if there is one.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I need to stop animations. I'm working on a patch, but not there yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a simple stop() function in my fork on [Github](https://github.com/sxross/zepto). This also triggers your callback.